# Suprimir nodo en una lista en posición P

Tags: c++

tengo un problema relacionado con las estructuras de datos, en este caso las listas en C++, mi problema está en suprimir un elemento de una lista en una posición dada.

Adjunto el main, y las clases nodo y lista

**Main**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Nodo.h"
#include "Lista.h"
using namespace std;


void menu();
Lista* lista= new Lista();

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    menu();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void menu(){
    int opcion,dato, posicion;

    do{
        cout<<"1. Agregar\n";
        cout<<"2. Imprimir\n";
        cout<<"3. Insertar\n";
        cout<<"4. Eliminar\n";
        cout<<"5. Vaciar lista\n";
        cout<<"6. Salir\n\n";
        cout<<"Opcion  ";

        cin>> opcion;
        switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            cout<<"Ingrese un numero ";
            cin>> dato;
            lista->agregar(dato, lista);
                break;
        case 2:
            lista->imprimirLista(lista);
            cout<<endl;
                break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"Ingrese un numero ";
            cin>>dato;
            cout<<"Ingrese la posicion ";
            cin>>posicion;
            lista->insertar(dato, posicion, lista);
                break;
        case 4:
            cout<<"Ingrese la posicion a eliminar ";
            cin>>posicion;
            lista->suprimir(posicion, lista);
                break;
        case 5:
            lista->vaciarLista(lista);
        }
    }while(opcion!=6);

}
```

**Clase Nodo**

```
#ifndef NODO_H
#define NODO_H


class Nodo {
private:
    int elemento;
    Nodo* siguiente;
protected:
public:
    Nodo();
    Nodo(int elemento, Nodo* siguiente);
    void setElemento(int elemento);
    int getElemento();
    void setSiguiente(Nodo* siguiente);
    Nodo* getSiguiente();
    ~Nodo();
};

Nodo::Nodo(int elemento, Nodo* siguiente){
    this->elemento = elemento;
    this->siguiente = siguiente;
}

Nodo:: Nodo(){
    elemento= 0;
    siguiente = NULL;
}

void Nodo::setElemento(int elemento){
    this->elemento = elemento;
}

int Nodo::getElemento(){
    return elemento;
}

void Nodo::setSiguiente(Nodo* siguiente){
    this->siguiente = siguiente;
}

Nodo* Nodo::getSiguiente(){
    return siguiente;
}
#endif
```

**Clase Lista**

```
#ifndef LISTA_H
#define LISTA_H
#include "Nodo.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Lista {
private:
    Nodo* primero;
protected:
public:
    Lista();
    void agregar(int x, Lista* lista);
    void insertar(int x, int p, Lista* lista);
    void imprimirLista(Lista* lista);
    bool estaVacia(Lista* lista);
    void suprimir(int p, Lista* lista);
    void vaciarLista(Lista* lista);
    ~Lista();
};



void Lista::agregar(int x, Lista* lista){
    Nodo* nodoNuevo = new Nodo(x, NULL);
    Nodo* estePrimero = lista->primero;
    if(lista->primero == NULL)
        lista->primero = nodoNuevo;
    else{
        Nodo* temp = estePrimero;
        while(temp->getSiguiente() != NULL){
            temp = temp->getSiguiente();
        }
        temp->setSiguiente(nodoNuevo);
    }
}

Lista::Lista(){
    this->primero = NULL;
}

void Lista::imprimirLista(Lista* lista){
    Nodo* nuevoNodo = lista->primero;
    while(nuevoNodo!=NULL){
        cout<<"["<< nuevoNodo->getElemento()<< "]";
        nuevoNodo = nuevoNodo->getSiguiente();
    }   
}

void Lista::insertar(int x, int p, Lista* lista){
    Nodo* estePrimero = lista->primero;
    if(p==0)
        agregar(x, lista);
    else
        {
        Nodo* temp = estePrimero;
        Nodo* temp2;
        Nodo* nuevoNodo = new Nodo(x, NULL);
        for(int i= 0; i < p; i++){
            temp2 = temp;
            temp= temp->getSiguiente();
        }
        temp2->setSiguiente(nuevoNodo);
        nuevoNodo->setSiguiente(temp);
    };
}

void Lista::suprimir(int p, Lista* lista){
    Nodo* estePrimero= lista->primero;

    if(estePrimero != NULL){
        if(p==0){
            Nodo* temporal= estePrimero;
            estePrimero= temporal->getSiguiente();
            temporal->setSiguiente(NULL);
            delete temporal;        
        }else{
            Nodo* temp= estePrimero;
            Nodo* aux1;
            Nodo* aux2;
            for(int i=0; i<p-1; i++){
                temp = temp->getSiguiente();

            }
            aux1= temp;
            aux2 = temp->getSiguiente()->getSiguiente();
            aux1->setSiguiente(aux2);
            temp = temp->getSiguiente();
            temp->setSiguiente(NULL);
            delete temp;
        }

    }
}

bool Lista::estaVacia(Lista* lista){
    if(lista->primero == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void Lista::vaciarLista(Lista* lista){
    delete lista->primero;

}


#endif
```

El problema central que tengo en este momento es cómo utilizar el destructor de la clase nodo, si tengo que implementar algo en el destructor `~Nodo();`

Comment: Ok, el problema esta en suprimr... y cual seria el problema.. me parece que tendrias que asignar lista->primero = esteprimero dentro de la funcion, pero sin datos especificos no se que decir

Comment: Es que la idea que tengo está en que pararme justo antes de llegar al nodo(un nodo anterior) luego de esto obtener las direcciones del que quiero antes y después del nodo a borrar, ahora, en lo que tengo dudas es cómo utilizar el destructor, tengo que hacer algo dentro del método?

Comment: Qué bien que encontraras la respuesta tú mismo. Nótese que en lugar de ponerla en la pregunta, deberías moverla a la sección de respuestas. Mira en [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](/help/self-answer) para más detalles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Copio la [respuesta que dio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/76519/revisions) el propio autor de la pregunta.</sub>

Ya lo he resuelto y explico cómo para que sirva de ayuda:

```
void Lista::suprimir(int p, Lista* lista){
    Nodo* estePrimero= lista->primero;

    if(estePrimero != NULL){
        if(p==0){
            Nodo* temporal= estePrimero;
            estePrimero= temporal->getSiguiente();
            temporal->setSiguiente(NULL);
            delete temporal;
            lista->primero= estePrimero;
        }else{
            Nodo* temp= estePrimero;
            Nodo* aux1;
            Nodo* aux2;
            for(int i=0; i<p-1; i++){
                temp = temp->getSiguiente();

            }
            aux1= temp;
            aux2 = temp->getSiguiente()->getSiguiente();

            temp = temp->getSiguiente();
            temp->setSiguiente(NULL);
            delete temp;
            aux1->setSiguiente(aux2);
        }

    }
}
```

Resulta que al final de cada `delete` me hacía falta actualizar las direcciones de memoria, por eso después del delete no apuntaban a nada supongo.

Comment: el metodo podria ser recursivo, mas bonito :)

Comment: @DanielPérez oh, tienes razón... te animo a publicarlo. Apenas copié la respuesta del autor de la pregunta, para que se viera más

Comment: Tambien noto que no se manejan correctamente los errores, pues puede que en el for se pase del rango de la lista, si vas a checkear para el primero deberias checkearla para todos

Comment: @DanielPérez como dije antes, esta es solamente la copia de la respuesta del propoi autor de la pregunta. Yo no programo en C++ y por lo que veo tú sí dominas del tema, por lo que te recomiendo añadir una respuesta con estos detalles.

Comment: el algoritmo esta bien, solo queria dejar los comentarios para que los demas usarios tomen nota antes de usar el codigo directamente